# Transforming Pandas Dataframe into JSON with Struct and Array structure for Upload to BigQuery

Tags: json, pandas, transformation

Suppose I have data from a DataFrame with columns `id`, `title`, and `category`, `subcategory`, and `sub-subcategory` that looks like:

```
_________________________________________________________________
| id | title        | cat          |  subcat     |    subsubcat |
|____|______________|______________|_____________|______________|
| 1  | My Book      | cat1         |  subcat1    |  subsubcat1  |
| 1  | My Book      | cat2         |  subcat2    |  subsubcat2  |
| 2  | My Other Book| othercat1    | othersubcat1| othersubcat1 |
| 2  | My Other Book| othercat2    | othersubcat2|       null   |
| 2  | My Other Book| othercat3    |     null    |       null   |
|_______________________________________________________________|
```

I want to turn into this into a (newline-delimited) json that has structure like:

```
[
{
 'id' : '1',
 'title' : 'My Book',
 'categoryHiearchies': [
      {'categories': ['category1', 'subcategory1', 'sub-subcategory1']},
      {'categories': ['category2', 'subcategory2', 'sub-subcategory2']}

   ]
},
{
 'id' : '2',
 'title' : 'My Other Book',
 'categoryHiearchies': [
      {'categories': ['othercategory1', 'othersubcategory1', 'othersub-subcategory1']},
      {'categories': ['othercategory2', 'othersubcategory2']},
      {'categories': ['othercategory3']},
   ]
}
]
```

in order to properly upload it to BigQuery.

Any ideas how to apply this transformation?

Comment: First, I think your output is not a valid json. Second, that was the expected output, but what does the original data look like that generates that output?

Comment: I added what input data looks like and think I fixed the json structure. Is this more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `null` are `Nan` values:

```
(df.set_index(['id','title'],append=True).stack()
   .groupby(level=[0,1,2]).agg(lambda x: {'categories':list(x)})
   .groupby(level=[1,2]).agg(list)
   .reset_index(name='categoryHiearchies')
   .to_json(orient='records', indent=2)   
)
```

which gives

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "title":"My Book",
    "categoryHiearchies":[
      {
        "categories":[
          "cat1",
          "subcat1",
          "subsubcat1"
        ]
      },
      {
        "categories":[
          "cat2",
          "subcat2",
          "subsubcat2"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "title":"My Other Book",
    "categoryHiearchies":[
      {
        "categories":[
          "othercat1",
          "othersubcat1",
          "othersubcat1"
        ]
      },
      {
        "categories":[
          "othercat2",
          "othersubcat2"
        ]
      },
      {
        "categories":[
          "othercat3"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: thank you for the very nice solution.  Question: if I need to also create another list/record structure inside a record, how would I do that?

Comment: I honestly don't know how to answer that.

Comment: fair enough haha